# How to add css class to the root of component?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I tried to add bootstrap grid classes to the movie-mage-card template like that and used movie-image-card component in movie-image-grid component.

**movie-image-card.component.html**

```
<div id="movie-image-card" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
</div>
```

**movie-image-grid**

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <movie-image-card></movie-image-card>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, this bootstrap grid classes does not work properly since movie-image-card itself does not have col-* class. Instead, I see extra wrapper.

[image]

The classes work if I add classes like below. However,  I do not want to add classes every time I use movie-image-card.

How to achieve this ??

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <movie-image-card class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></movie-image-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
host: {'class': 'col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'}
```

to your component decorator.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yo8fiskwBwX83uLgKWca?p=preview